# How to resolve SwiftData error "Type '*' does not conform to protocol 'PersistentModel'"

Tags: swift, ios17, swift-data

Working through the betas of SwiftData and trying to stand up a `PersistentContainer`. I set up a `modelContainer` View modifier on my `ContentView` and conformed my class to `@Model` as described in various WWDC videos (the ones that are out).

Here is the base object I want to store, where all the variables conform to `Codable`:

`Board.swift`

```swift
import SwiftData

@Model
class Board {
    var size: Int = 3
    var cellSize: CGFloat = 44
    var numberOfTeamMembers: Int = 3
    var numberOfEnemies: Int = 3
    var spaces: [[Space]] = []
    var selectedSpace: Space? = nil
    var characters: [Space: Character] = [:]
    var selectedCharacter: Character? = nil
    var attackableSpaces: [Space] = []
    var movableSpaces: [Space] = []
    var teams: [Team] = []
    var localTeam: Team? = nil
    var currentTeam: Team? = nil
    var gamePhase: GamePhase = GamePhase.pickTeam
    var actions: [Action] = []
    var unoccupiedSpaces: [Space] = []
    var tilt: CGFloat = 1
    var availableMoves: [UUID: [TurnPhase]] = [:]
    var turn: Turn = Turn.mine
}
```

`ContentView.swift`

```swift
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(for: [Board.self])
    }
}
```

I'm seeing the following compilation errors:

[image: SwiftData errors]

> Type 'Board' does not conform to protocol 'PersistentModel'

> No exact matches in call to instance method 'setValue'

Tried implementing as documentation describes, but it doesn't quite work. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: We don't know much about SwiftData yet... But it seems that 'Team' does not conform 'PersistentModel' (try using @Model for 'Team') and this makes 'Board' have problem with 'PersistentModel'.

Comment: Space, Team, TurnPhase, Action
where are these declared and how?
whatever custom ds you are using should be marked with @Model

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing and the one thing I've worked out that if the _usage_ of the variable is private, (i.e. in a `View`) the error disappears.  Maybe something about compiler elision?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I've tried conforming the inner models to `Codable`, making them `@Model` and marking them as `@Relation` in the parent object. But so far no luck at all :( I'm hoping to find the answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your implementation is correct, but there is a bug in the Swift compiler ([now fixed](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/66532) but not yet in Xcode 15.0 beta 2) that prevents this from working.  The bug is related to the visibility of macro expansions from other scopes so the work around is to remove the `#Preview`s on Views that take macro'd (e.g. `@Model`) types as arguments.

**Note:** credit for this discovery and workaround go to [Holly Borla](https://hachyderm.io/@holly/110561326299156776).

**Update:** This appears to be fixed in Xcode 15.0 beta 3.

Answer (score 3):

I've got the exact same errors:

```
No exact matches in call to instance method 'setValue'
No exact matches in call to instance method 'getValue'
```

In my case the problem was the types in the models. I've defined a few enums to help me reason about certain things. But these types weren't marked with the `@Model` macro. And somehow the compiler couldn't resolve the macros around these and has thrown the errors as above.

For me what worked, was simply changing in the model the type from `enum` to its `rawValue` type and save that instead. Possibly one of your types `Space`, `Character`, `Team`... also uses an enum or other unsupported type?

Overall changing the types to a basic ones (like Int, Double, String etc) is less than ideal solution, possibly there's a better workaround, but for a month old technology, I can continue exploring what's there and hopefully we'll get some better examples on how to store things.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot CoreData didn't support enums.

Comment: Ran into this again today. I was able to add Codable to my enums and fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

The error itself means the Xcode couldn't build the project and generate the necessary codes to conform you class marked with `@Model` to the `PersistentModel` protocol. In other words, it tells you nothing about the actual problem!

I had the similar problem and tried all of the random solutions mentioned in the comments and as answers, but non of them worked so I decided to create a new project and copy-paste my codes piece by piece until it breaks! Here's what was the error in my case:

I have one class marked with `@Model`, it contains a `Date` object and two custom typed `array`s. In my Home screen, I fetch data like this:

```swift
@Query(
  sort: [SortDescriptor(\.date, order: .reverse)]
) private var items: [Item]
```

and I show them in a `List` like this:

```swift
List(selection: $detailSelection) {
  ForEach(items) { item in
    NavigationLink(destination: {
      ItemDetailsView(item: item)
    }, label: {
      HomeItemRow(item: item)
    })
  }
}
```

**The problem was in the `ItemDetailsView` screen where I defined the initializer like:**

```swift
init(item: Item) {
  self.item = item
}
```

When I changed it to have a default value, it fixed the build error!!

```swift
init(item: Item = Item(date: .now)) {
  self.item = item
}
```

I hope this saves you a ton of headaches

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, Xcode kind of freaks out and doesn't really help you out in this situation.

Fortunately/unfortunately, when I transitioned a model from a custom `struct` to a SwiftData `@Model`, I forgot to flip it into a `class`... I fixed my problem by changing my `@Model` to a `class`. That was it.

```swift
// Produces the "Does not conform to protocol 'PersistentModel'" error
@Model struct MyModel { ... }

// Works: Fixed by replacing `struct` with `class`
@Model class MyModel { ... }
```

Happens to the best of us lol. Best of luck figuring this one out.

Answer (score 0):

If `Space`, `Team`, `GamePhase`, `TurnPhase`, `Turn` conforms to `Codable` or is `PersistentModel` than the problem would be `Swift.Character`.

`Character` does not conforms to `Codable` so you can't put that type directly.

Comment: This looks correct, OP probably has a custom type Character but the compiler probably doesn’t understand that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure `Board` conforms to `Hashable` and `Identifiable`. Note that classes do not automatically generate Hashable conformance.

Looking at the `PersistentModel` protocol:

`protocol PersistentModel : AnyObject, Observable, Hashable, Identifiable`

The `@Model` macro expansion includes conformance to `Observable` and `PersistentModel`, so you need to add extensions to make sure `Board` conforms to the others like so:

```
extension Board: Identifiable, Hashable {
// ... Hashable protocol stubs
}
```

Comment: looks like the right answer, but after conformance the protocols still doesn't work :(
We just have to wait for the new beta version, which will fix everything.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell which properties cause these errors since I can't see implementation of all property classes.

One of the things you can try in order to troubleshoot is to mark properties with **@Transient** one-by-one. This macro prevents the persistence on the particular parameter it is applied to. Don't forget to remove the **@Transient** macro when no longer needed.

For example:

```
@Transient var localTeam: Team? = nil
@Transient var actions: [Action] = []
```

Answer (score -8):

> [SwiftData uses the proven storage architecture of Core Data [...]](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/swiftdata/)

This means that we need to implement our data model like we do for Core Data.

What do we do in Core Data? We create Data Model file (.xcdatamodeld) and create entities, relationships, codgen, delete rules, etc. Then we go to *Editor -> Create NSManagedObject Sublcass...* and let Xcode create Swift files for our data models.

This *might* apply in the same way for SwiftData, too. (We don't know everything about SwiftData yet... We still need more information from WWDC 2023 sessions.) But I found out that you can create data models in the same way on Xcode by creating swift files with SwiftData models from .xcdatamodeld. If you go to *Editor -> Create SwiftData Code...*, Xcode will generate SwiftData codes for you.

The type should be supported by Core Data, I guess. The supported types by Core Data right now are Int16, Int32, Int64, Decimal, Double, Float, String, Boolean, Date, Binary Data, UUID, URI, and Transformable. You can also make parent-child relationships with other entities, too.

[This article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/modeling_data) and the articles in **Topic** section explain how you can make Core Data Model.

**Remember**: The only technical information that we know about SwiftData is that it is based on Core Data, so we should go for the safest way which is to do what we do for Core Data.